# HTTP Request -> GSLB sticky persistence logic

Tags: load-balancing, f5, internal-load-balancer, gslb

Application `HTTP` request flow as follows

```
1) The request comes to GTM#1
2) GTM#1 request will send to LTM#A or LTM#B
3) Servers under LTM# A or B will send request to GTM#2
4) GTM#2 will have again LTM# X or Y
5) The response goes back to the same flow
```

Note: LTM#A and X will be in one location and B&Y will be in another location

I would want to implement sticky persistent logic.

Which configuration should I setup

Answer (score 1):

Separate out your traffic flow for a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

From a DNS resolution perspective, GTM can only use LDNS or client persistence. GTM only responds with A records at the initiation of the session, once resolution has happened then the DNS name will remain for however long the client cache allows.

From an application flow perspective, Sticky persistence is performed at the LTM application level and, depending on the application, can be cookie (http/https), session, headers, source ip based.

Your safest bet is to configure LDNS persistence on the GTM and cookie persistence at the LTM for HTTP traffic or source-IP persistence for non HTTP traffic.